# How can one create an open web interface to a Python script that accepts and returns text?

Tags: python, html, web

I have a Python script that accepts text from a user, interprets that text and then produces a text response for that user. I want to create a simple web interface to this Python script that is accessible to multiple people at once. By this I mean that person A can go to the website for the script and begin interacting with the script and, at the same time, person B can do the same. This would mean that the script is running in as many processes/sessions as desired.

What would be a good way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try a python web framework like django or flask .etc
Make a simple website that offers a webpage that contians a form to input text ,and when people visit the url, put their text in the form and submit, your code can handle it and return a webpage to show the result.